# How can i fix 'Settings' is inaccessible due to its protection level error?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0122  'Settings' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The error is on the line: On the Settings

```
path = PathHelper.GetWithBackslash(Core.Settings.Default.DownloadFolder);
```

And the Settings definition

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class marked as `internal` is accessible only inside assembly it is declared.

There are two possible solutions:

You should make it `public`:

```
public sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
```

**OR**

**[Possible solution, but first is better]**

If you don't want to make it `public` you can set `friend assembly`. Friend assembly can access to internal types in other assembly:

Put this line in file with your `Settings` after `using` directives:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourAssemblyName")] //set name of assembly from which you want to access to Settings
```

Comment: Your second option is an awful hack though.

Comment: @DavidG, agree, but C# provides this feature. Also, it can be useful if you don't need to make `internal` types visible to all assemblies, only to particular.

Comment: C# also provides the [`goto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) statement but if anyone suggested that, I'd gladly mock them! :)

Comment: Be aware that there's a really annoying thing that happens if you make the `Settings` class public AND turn on XML comments - you'll get warnings from the IDE-generated code about missing XML comments! There is another way to fix this though: Create a public DTO type to hold the settings and use THAT in external assemblies. Might be better than using the `Settings` class directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the answer of Roma Doskoch more clear:
if you do want to make your settings public make sure to set this in the designer:
[image] 
unless you do this, at every time that you will save the settings from the designer the public will be overwritten.

if you do not want to make the setting public, put the code mentioned in the file "AssemblyInfo.cs" in the properties folder